# java, else if "Error: illegal start of expression"

Tags: java

//the idea of the code if to see is point is in a rectangle. The input is a 6 digit number (abcdef). the top left corner of the rectangle has coordinates (a,b), the right lower (c,d) and the point (e,f)

```
enter codeimport java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle{
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 public static void run() {
 int object;
 System.out.println("input:");
 object = sc.nextInt();

 if(object/100000 >= (object/1000)%10 || (object/10000)%10 <= (object/100)%10){
   System.out.print("inside");
 }else if (object/100000 <= (object/10)%10 && (object/10)%10 <= (object/1000)%10 && (object/100)%10) <= object%10 && object%10 <= (object/10000)%10){
   System.out.print("inside");
 }else {
   System.out.print("outside");
 }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ( new Rectangle()).run();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Check parenthesis in if statement ...

Comment: Why do you have a random opening bracer in your main method?

Comment: Your `run` method is missing a closing `}` after your `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have extra `)` in third condition in `else if` statement.

```
else if (object/100000 <= (object/10)%10 && 
         (object/10)%10 <= (object/1000)%10 && 
         (object/100)%10 remove it--->) <= object%10 && 
           object%10 <= (object/10000)%10){
```

Also you cannot reference non static `'Scanner sc'` in static method, make `Scanner sc`  as static or `run()` method non static.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are wrong, please use the formatting of your code tool. I post the fixed code below. Note that the condition must be wrapped between `()` brackets.

```
if (condition) { ... }

// In case there are complete calculations within condition
if ((condition) && (condition) && (condition)) { ... }
```

Moreover it surely says:

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

This error should be fixed by removing the `static` keyword since you use the instance of `Scanner` that's not static as well.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void run() {
    int object;
    System.out.println("input:");
    object = sc.nextInt();

    if (object / 100000 >= (object / 1000) % 10 || (object / 10000) % 10 <= (object / 100) % 10) {
        System.out.print("inside");
    } else if (((object / 100000 <= (object / 10) % 10) && 
            ((object / 10) % 10 <= (object / 1000) % 10) && 
            ((object / 100) % 10) <= object % 10) && 
            (object % 10 <= (object / 10000) % 10)) 
    {
        System.out.print("inside");
    } else {
        System.out.print("outside");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Rectangle().run();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, and sorry for the post mistakes, I'm posting for the first time

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for :)) Please consider to select the most helpful answer here as accepted and make this question amswered.